# PowerBI embed token with RLS through C# API

Tags: c#, powerbi

We want to provide embedded PowerBI reports to our customers. Initially, we're looking at using one report with a dataset that contains data for all customers. I have created a service principal (app only auth) that has access to a workspace where I've published the report. I've also created a role "business_customer" with a DAX expression ([CustomerNumber] = USERNAME()) on this report.

I'm trying to get an embed token for the report with row level security through the C# API (Microsoft.PowerBI.Api):

```
var tenantId = "<tenantId>";
var datasetId = "<datasetId>";
var reportId = "<reportId>";
var groupId = "<groupId>";
var applicationPassword = "<applicationPassword>";

var context = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/");
var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(applicationId, applicationPassword);
var result = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api",
   clientCredential).Result;

var authHeader = new TokenCredentials(result.AccessToken, "Bearer");
var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri("https://api.powerbi.com"), authHeader);
var groups = client.Groups.GetGroups();

var tokenRequest = new GenerateTokenRequest(TokenAccessLevel.View, datasetId,
   new EffectiveIdentity("username", new List<string> { datasetId },
   new List<string> { "business_customer" }));

var embedToken = client.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroupAsync(new Guid(groupId), new Guid(reportId), 
   tokenRequest, cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

This fails on the GenerateTokenInGroupsAsync call:

```
"Invalid request: Creating embed token for accessing dataset <datasetId> shouldn't have effective identity"
```

I've tried with different usernames and I've tried leaving the username blank, but all of my attempts have failed.

Is there a way of getting an embed token this way or am I on the wrong path? What would be the "correct" way of solving this case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure the published report actually has RLS, because one of the reasons to get this message is that the report has no RLS in it. Also what is the data source and the dataset for this report? what is the value of dataset's `IsEffectiveIdentityRequired` property?

Comment: @AndreyNikolov I have defined a role with a DAX expression - but that's not the RLS criteria you're after? The data source is a MySQL database and the dataset's `IsEffectiveIdentityRequired` is `false`.